# cURL PHP request headers with variables not working

Tags: php, curl, request-headers

So I want to post some headers, but I'm having trouble using variables in them.

As an example (this works):

```
$headers = array();
...
$headers[] = "Content-Length: 96";
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

But I want this (which doesn't work apparently):

```
$arr = "string-with-a-length-of-108";
$headers = array();
...
$headers[] = "Content-Length: ".(strlen($arr)-12);
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Think it's an easy fix, but I have no clue why this shouldn't work. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Okay I fixed it, it works fine if I just do the following:

```
$length = strlen($arr)-12;
...
$headers[] = "Content-Length: $length";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can, I will suggest you use postman[https://www.getpostman.com/postman] to handle your cURL requests. It's pretty easy to use.

Comment: There is not really a problem in handling the requests except that I need the proper syntax for using variables in headers (in PHP).

Comment: mykoman this doesn't answer the question. Y.Terz hasn't asked with what other library can he handle the headers but how to solve the problem he has in using php functions

Answer (score 0):

I also think the second one should work, checking some of my code I found I send headers like this, check if this helps:

```
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array (
                    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1" ,
                    "Accept-Encoding: gzip"         
            ) );
```

Comment: You haven't use any variables in your header array here, so it's not really helpful.